# Is there any way to change %USERPROFILE% for one application only?

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles

Well my question is just what is says in the title:
I have a application that seems to have charset conversion issues with my %USERPROFILE% directory. Is there any way to change the location of %USERPROFILE% for only that one application?

Comment: In what context are you using %USERPROFILE% for this application? I take it you don't want to simply specify the actual location of that folder to it?

Comment: @Jonno I do want to do exactly that. The application tries to make subdirectories by using %USERPROFILE%  for the path. Then it seems to incorrectly handle the path and directory creation fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is (may not work for every application):

1. Create a text file and rename it to `<whateveryoulike>.bat`, Make sure the file type changes to `Windows Batch file`
2. Open the file in any text editor (Editor is enough)

   1. Line: `set USERPROFILE="(the absolute path you like the userprofile variable to point to)"`
   2. Line: call your executable, either with an absolute path or a relative path
3. Launch it. If it doesn't work, try to run it as Administrator; if it then doesn't work as well, then that application is incompatible with this method.

Comment: Well looks like this solution doesn't work with this particular application for some reason. Still, +1 for providing a general answer to the question!

Comment: What application in particular? Maybe there is another solution to your problem.

Comment: The application is called FL-DIGI and I can't find any errors specific to it.

Comment: You get the tick. I just had to run the batch file as administrator to get the path to work.

Comment: Thanks, I add that to my answer to make sure other users can solve similar issues.